# how can I select first image from db stored as json ? thanks

Tags: mysql

I have images stored like : ["first.jpg,"second.png"]
How can I get the first image ? 
I tried to solve it in php but i'm not pleased with it

Comment: There isn't a defined order within SQL.. you atleast need a column on where you can indentify the order iike a int column with `PRIMARY KEY` with `AUTO_INCREMENT` option or a datetime column with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` option.. Then you can use `ORDER BY [column] ASC LIMIT 1` to fetch the first record.. Using  `LIMIT 1` without `ORDER BY` isn't stabile because SQL is free to return the record in anny order so that means the second record can also be returned

Comment: Which MySQL version? Are there always going to be items in the list? What was your solution in PHP? Why didn't you like it?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking.  Do you have multiple "image" records and you want to get "the first" from a selected set?  Do you have a single column containing a JSON BLOB and you want to get an item from the JSON?  Something else?  Please elaborate on what you're attempting and where you're stuck.

Comment: I have multiple products, and all of them have a single column containing 1-5 images stored as json and i would like to get the first string that contains the jpg format and then concatenate the string with another string so i can make a link from it

Comment: in php it is not good because it gives me more work when I insert it in a csv file

Comment: PHP version: 7.2.2 , and yes, there will always be items in the list